# Triggering lambda function from creation of DynamoDB table

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way to cause the creation of a new DynamoDB table to trigger a lambda function?

From what I see DynamoDB events are tied to existing tables and I can't see an option of having a "global" event.

Comment: There are EventBridge CloudTrail events for all management api actions, e.g. CreateTable. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-service-event.html - you just need to configure a rule to match the events you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks @luk2302, do you happen to have a more detailed guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DynamoDB Streams to trigger an event, its only for Dataplane operations. As CreateTable is a control plane API, its not possible to use streams.

However, you can use CloudWatchEvents/EventBridge. You can have it trigger when an API event is recored in CloudTrail, which in turn can invoke your Lambda function.

You can learn more here [Creating a CloudWatch Events Rule That Triggers on an AWS API Call Using AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-CloudTrail-Rule.html)

Comment: *"**Note** Amazon EventBridge is the preferred way to manage your events. CloudWatch Events and EventBridge are the same underlying service and API, but EventBridge provides more features."*

Comment: Both are the same thing only that CW docs events shows the how-to for this specific purpose, EB does not.